# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError when returning class instead of interface

Tags: php, class, oop, interface

I ran into a bizarre issue with PHP type system. I have the following interface and class:

```
interface IDB { ... }

class DB implements IDB { ... }
```

I then try to return an instance of DB class like this:

```
public function GetDB(): IDB {
    return new DB();
}
```

This works as expected on my local Wampserver. However, when I uploaded this to my hosting provider (which uses PHP 8.2), I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: GetDB(): Return value must be of type IDB, DB returned`

Have been going back and forth for a while now and I'm really confused about this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This works as expected for me. https://3v4l.org/7EVHG. My only guesses is that one of the files isn’t being uploaded correctly, or you have `DB` classes, possibly with an autoloader, and the wrong one is being invoked.